# OpenGL multitexture tessellation

Tags: opengl

I have to tessellate some surface in OpenGL with rectangular textures. Let it be a single triangle for simplicity. The textures touch each other by sides, and do not overlap. That is done by setting GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S and GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T to GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER and adjusting texture coords properly. Everything goes fine while GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER is set to GL_NEAREST, but when I want to apply GL_LINEAR filering and/or anisotropic filtering following arifact apperas: textures border pixel's alpha gradually fall to transparent, so that line of background color is visible between neighbouring textures.

How can I avoid this artifact without merging multiple textures to one while linear filtering is preserved?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` instead of `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER`. Clamp to border mixes the edge pixel with the border color, which is initialized to (0,0,0,0). This is where your transparency is coming from.

Either clamp the texture to the actual edge, or set a border color that is nontransparent.

Comment: The point is to render texture upon surface as a single rectangular block (outer space of the block must remain transparent) though adjacent textures sould border each other without gaps.